# Caching the result of all methods

Tags: caching, reflection, smalltalk, pharo

I have a class which is essentially a collection of methods for some data transformations. In another words I have some data in my files and I use a few different code snippets to transform the textual data into something that I can easily query.

Now the methods often reuse each-other and as the core data is changing I'd like to simply cache the results of each method, for the speed reasons.

I don't want to change each method by adding:

```
^ methodsCache ifNil: [ methodsCache := "compute" ]
```

I want to use the power of Pharo reflection to accomplish my task without touching much of code.

*One idea that I had is if I can run some code before each method, thing I can either return a cached value or continue the execution of the method and cache it's result*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Reflectivity framework to add pre and post meta links to your methods. A link could check a cache before execution transparently.

```
link := MetaLink new
    metaObject: self;
    selector: #cachedExecute:;
    arguments: #(selector);
    control: #before.
(MyClass>>#myMethodSelector) ast link: link.
```

This code will install a meta link that sends `#cachedExecute:` to a `MyClass` object with the argument `#myMethodSelector`. The link is installed on the first AST node of the compiled method (of that same method selector, but could be on another method). The `#control:` message ensures that the link will be executed before the AST node is executed.

You can of course install multiple meta links that influence each other.

Note that in the above example you **must not** send the same message (`#myMethodSelector`) again inside of the `#cachedExecute:` method since you'd end up in a loop.

**Update**
There's actually an error in the code above (now fixed). The `#arguments:` message takes a list of symbols that define the parameters of the method specified via `#selector:`. Those arguments will be *reified* from the context. To pass the method selector you's use the `#selector` reification, for the method context the `#context` reification and for method arguments `#arguments`. To see which reifications are available, look at the `#key` on the class side of the subclasses of `RFReification`.

Comment: Thanks Max, this is a very nice example. Do you have any idea how I can also redirect the parameters of the method?

Comment: Another question is how do I perform the `cachedExecute:`? Can I call a "clean" version of my method? Can I return some value instead of running the rest of the method?

Comment: You could install an `#after` link that installs an `#instead` link on the same method *after* the method execution has been cached. The `#instead` link will then return the cached value (it replaces the entire AST of the method).

Answer (score 0):

One idea that I had is to define

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage

    aMessage selector beginsWith: 'cached' ifFalse: [ ^ super doesNotUnderstand: aMessage ].

    ^ cache at: aMessage selector ifAbsentPut: [ 
        self perform: aMessage selector allButFirst: 6 ]
```

This way the only thing you have to do is to replace all message sends like `self methodName` with `self cachedmethodName` (or `self cachedMethodName` but then you have to do additional lowercase workaround in `doesNotUnderstand:`)

Answer (score 0):

Another well-known option would be to replace your new and return a caching proxy, delegating to the actual object